# cross-database references are not implemented:

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to convert SQL inner join query into PostgreSQL inner join query. In this inner join query which tables are using that all tables are not present in one database. we separated tables into two databases i.e. application db and security db

1. users and permission table are present in security db
2. userrolemapping and department are present in application db

I tried like below but I am getting following error

**Error**

```
ERROR:  cross-database references are not implemented: "Rockefeller_ApplicationDb.public.userrolemapping"
LINE 4:         INNER JOIN "Rockefeller_ApplicationDb".public.userro..
```

**SQL Stored Function**

```
SELECT   Department.nDeptID 
    FROM Users INNER JOIN Permission 
         ON Users.nUserID = Permission.nUserID INNER JOIN UserRoleMapping
         ON Users.nUserID = UserRoleMapping.nUserID INNER JOIN Department
         ON Permission.nDeptInst = Department.nInstID
         AND  Department.nInstID = 60
    WHERE     
         Users.nUserID = 3;
```

**PostgreSQL Stored Function**

```
SELECT dep.ndept_id 
        FROM "Rockefeller_SecurityDb".public.users as  u 
        INNER JOIN  "Rockefeller_SecurityDb".public.permissions p ON u.nuser_id = p.nuser_id
        INNER JOIN "Rockefeller_ApplicationDb".public.userrolemapping as urm ON u.nuser_id = urm.nuser_id
        INNER JOIN "Rockefeller_ApplicationDb".public.department dep ON p.ndept_inst = dep.ninst_id
           AND  dep.ninst_id = 60
                        WHERE     
                            u.nuser_id = 3;
```

Comment: See [dblink documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html).

Answer (score 47):

You cannot join tables from different databases.

Databases are logically separated in PostgreSQL by design.

If you want to join the tables, you should put them into different schemas in one database rather than into different databases.

Note that what is called “database” in MySQL is called a “schema” in standard SQL.

If you really need to join tables from different databases, you need to use a foreign data wrapper.

Comment: means you are saying  we  can not join two tables which are in two different db. if it is one db and two different schema then we can perform join

Comment: but requirement is two separated db and joining. There is no way to do this

Comment: Change the requirement. If the customer is too stubborn to listen to good advice, use foreign tables with postgres_fdw.

Comment: @springuser there is no way to do that in mysql either.

Comment: Wow. I do cross-database joins on the same server all the time! I am shocked that mysql and postgres won't allow this.

Comment: @WilliamChiu This is actually a benefit, since it allows you to separate data securely. If you want to join tables, you can put them in different schemas in the same database.

Comment: MS Access 2003 has this ability with ODBC connections for as long as 20 years.

Comment: @PaulVerschoor At least some of us consider that separation to be a feature. If you need to join data from two tables, why put them in separate databases rather than in different schemas?

Answer (score 13):

For future searchs, you can to use dblink to connect to other database.

Follow commands:

```
create extension dblink;

SELECT dblink_connect('otherdb','host=localhost port=5432 dbname=otherdb user=postgres password=???? options=-csearch_path=');

SELECT * FROM dblink('otherdb', 'select field1, field2 from public.tablex')
AS t(field1 text, field2 text);
```

Answer (score 5):

New to postrgreSQL and I had the same requirement. FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER did the job.

[IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA — import table definitions from a foreign server](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-importforeignschema.html)

But first I had to:

1. enable the fdw extension
2. define the foreign server (which was the locahost in this case!)
3. create a mapping between the local user and the foreign user.

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;

CREATE SERVER localsrv
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
OPTIONS (host 'localhost', dbname 'otherdb', port '5432');

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR <local_user>
SERVER localsrv
OPTIONS (user 'ohterdb_user', password 'ohterdb_user_password');

IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA public
FROM SERVER localsrv 
INTO public;
```

After that I could use the foreign tables as if they were local. I did not notice any performance cost.

Answer (score -1):

As others have said FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER does work but with some caveats.

You have to create a foreign table for each table , it's not like a linked server in MSSQL

The biggest drawback is performance, indexes on the foreign tables seem to be ignored and you can't index them locally. you can try running ANALYZE on the foreign table which helps but not much.

Comment: The comment about indexes not used, is definitely not true. We would not be able to pick a single record out of a couple of billion records in a foreign table within a millisecond if there wouldn't be an index.